# Hide/change collapse [-] and expand [ ] button on JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, expand

Is there a way to hide the collapse [-] and expand [+] button on a java file `JTree`?

If it's not possible, is there a way to change it to a different icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes to both: You can specify an empty `Icon`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263600/230513). You can substitute your own implementation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641530/230513). These are the relevant `UIManager` keys:

```
UIManager.put("Tree.collapsedIcon", empty);
UIManager.put("Tree.expandedIcon", empty);
```