# Is there a way to make discrete signal plots in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, plot, jfreechart

I want to make a discrete signal plot in Java, like when using the [stem() command in matlab](https://la.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html?lang=en), such that when giving it an array for the x-axis and one for the y-axis, it makes like a scatter plot with a vertical line connected to x-axis.

I have tried using JFreeChart to do this, but it doesn't have a discrete plot specifically. The closest I came to it was asking ChatGPT to make a scatter plot and connect the lines to the bottom and it gave me this code:

```
package z;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.RectangleInsets;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;

public class ScatterPlotWithLines extends ApplicationFrame {

    public ScatterPlotWithLines(String title) {
        super(title);

        // Create a dataset with 10 random data points
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = createScatterDataset(10);

        // Create the scatter plot
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
                "Scatter Plot with Lines",
                "X-Axis Label",
                "Y-Axis Label",
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
        );

        // Customize the plot and renderer for scatter points (optional)
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

        // Customize the renderer for scatter points (e.g., change the shape and color of points)
        Shape pointShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6); // Example shape
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, pointShape);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);

        // Create a dataset for lines connecting the data points to the x-axis
        DefaultXYDataset lineDataset = createLineDataset(dataset);

        // Create a renderer for the lines
        XYItemRenderer lineRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
        lineRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red); // Line color

        plot.setDataset(1, lineDataset); // Add the line dataset to the plot
        plot.setRenderer(1, lineRenderer); // Set the line renderer for the new dataset

        // Set margin for the plot
        plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));

        // Create a ChartPanel and add it to the frame
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private XYSeriesCollection createScatterDataset(int numPoints) {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Scatter Plot");

        // Generate random data points for the series
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
            double x = rand.nextDouble() * 10;
            double y = rand.nextDouble() * 10;
            series.add(x, y);
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series);

        return dataset;
    }

    private DefaultXYDataset createLineDataset(XYSeriesCollection scatterDataset) {
        DefaultXYDataset lineDataset = new DefaultXYDataset();

        // Create lines connecting data points to the x-axis
        for (int i = 0; i < scatterDataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            XYSeries scatterSeries = scatterDataset.getSeries(i);
            double[][] lineData = new double[2][scatterSeries.getItemCount() * 2];

            for (int j = 0; j < scatterSeries.getItemCount(); j++) {
                double x = scatterSeries.getX(j).doubleValue();
                double y = scatterSeries.getY(j).doubleValue();

                // Add the data point
                lineData[0][j * 2] = x;
                lineData[1][j * 2] = y;

                // Connect to the x-axis
                lineData[0][j * 2 + 1] = x;
                lineData[1][j * 2 + 1] = 0;
            }

            lineDataset.addSeries("Lines", lineData);
        }

        return lineDataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ScatterPlotWithLines example = new ScatterPlotWithLines("Scatter Plot with Lines");
            example.pack();
            example.setDefaultCloseOperation(ApplicationFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            example.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

and it works, sort of:

[image: Stem plot?]

I understand it made a different dataset and connected the dots, but is it possible to have it just with the vertical lines? I know I can do this easily using other languages like Python and MatLab, I just want to know if it's possible to do it in Java.

Comment: if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck then it is a duck, on a side note, you could use a zero before and after your point to make it look more like `stem`.

Comment: Damn, it was really that simple ahhaha, that solved it, thanks.

Comment: @trashgod I checked it out and it also looks like a discrete signal, but since the x-axis are categories, and not numbers, i would have to input each number as a string into its own category which is just a little bit more annoying to do. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

As @Ahmed AEK [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77113602/is-there-a-way-to-make-discrete-signal-plots-in-java#comment135942419_77113602), you can adjust your dataset to "make it look more like [stem](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html)." Also consider,

- [`HighLowRenderer`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/HighLowRenderer.html), suitable for continuous data; the methods `setDrawCloseTicks()` and `setDrawOpenTicks()` control tick mark visibility.
- [`MinMaxCategoryRenderer`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/MinMaxCategoryRenderer.html), suitable for category data; the icons can be replaced with custom implementations, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641530/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263600/230513).