# Assinging different icons to different nodes in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Is it possible to assign different icons to different nodes in a `JTree` using `DefaultTreeCellRenderer.setOpenIcon()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same cell renderer instance is used to render all the cells of the tree. The open icon is the little + symbol, or triangle symbol at the left of every tree node which allows to expand it (i.e. see its child nodes). I doubt this is the icon you want to change. It would be rather strange not to use the same one for all the nodes.

If you want to display a custom icon for a specific node, create a subclass of DefaultTreeCellRenderer, override the [`getTreeCellRendererComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html#getTreeCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JTree,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20boolean%29) method, decide which icon to display based on the value passed to the method, and call `setIcon`.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display for a similar example (which customized the tooltip, and not the icon, but the idea is the same).

Comment: See also [`TreeIcon`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640818/change-jtree-node-icons-according-to-the-depth-level/4641530#4641530).

Comment: Thank you both JB Nizet and trashgod