# How to give the JFrame a different look-and-feel from other components (Multiplexing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

This method

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceCeruleanLookAndFeel());
```

sets the L&F for the whole app. How do I combine this and then set different L&F just for `JFrame`?

**EDIT**

I've found this article on [*Multiplexing Look and Feels*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/multi/doc-files/multi_tsc.html). How exactly does this work? I can't find any examples.

Comment: why? Anyway, simply don't - Swing is designed to support a single LAF per application. Typically, mixing will result in unpredictable visuals and behaviour. As @trashgod already noted, JFrame is _not_ a JComponent, that is, it has no ui delegate to set .. the only thingy that might be taken over by the LAF is the frame decoration, see JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecoration

Comment: So, can i use one laf for the whole app, and decorate frames using another laf? Or vice versa; use one laf, but then tell all components except frame decoration use another laf? Is this possible? I dont have skills to create my own laf so i wondered is there a way to combine lafs to make stuff look nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override UI defaults for a `JComponent` easily enough; there's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641530/230513) that illustrates changing `JTree` icons. Unfortunately, `JFrame` is not a `JComponent`; it has no UI delegate, and its decorations are supplied by the host operating system.

For more specific guidance, you'll need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

See also [*Validation overlays using multiplex look and feel*](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/08/06/validation-overlays-using-multiplex-look-and-feel.html).

Comment: thanks for response. But frames with substance laf has customized look i mean iconify and close buttons, some lafs has their windows with rounded corners. Can i somehow fetch this from one laf, and add to another?

Comment: @bunnyjesse112 no - it's either the LAF decoration or OS provided. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, the look and feel is application wide.