# Customizing Tree.collapsedIcon for a single JTree

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree, uimanager

I know that you can change the `Tree.collapsedIcon` for a all `JTrees` in an application using Swing using the `UImanager`.  For example:

```
UIManager.put("Tree.collapsedIcon",closedcabinet);
```

I would like the flexibility of changing the `Tree.collapsedIcon` for individual `JTrees` in the same application with the end result being that the `Tree.collpasedIcon` could appear differently for different trees in the same application.

I know how to customize individual icons using a custom renderer.   For example, I use `setIcon` to set the icon of a leaf, `SetOpenIcon` to set the icon for a node that has children when its expanded and `SetCloseIcon` to do the same for nodes that are not.

But I don't see how to do this for the `Tree.collapsedIcon` other than use the `UIManager` which has the limitations as described above.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: *"Thanks,

Elliott"*  By 1100+ rep. you should have figured that 4 lines of sig. is not welcome.  -1

Comment: curious: why the downvotes? Looks like a good question to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach is to condition the `UIManager` when constructing each tree. In the example below, static factories provide the required `Icon` pair. The example borrows two icons from the `MetalLookAndFeel` for contrast. Custom icons, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641530/230513), are also possible.

```
frame.add(new JTreePanel(Icons.getDefault()));
frame.add(new JTreePanel(Icons.getMetal()));
```

[image]

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262706/230513 */
public class JTreePanel extends JPanel {

    public static final class Icons {

        private static final String COLLAPSED_ICON = "Tree.collapsedIcon";
        private static final String EXPANDED_ICON = "Tree.expandedIcon";
        private Icon collapsed;
        private Icon expanded;

        public static Icons getDefault() {
            Icons icons = new Icons();
            icons.collapsed = (Icon) UIManager.get(COLLAPSED_ICON);
            icons.expanded = (Icon) UIManager.get(EXPANDED_ICON);
            return new Icons();
        }

        public static Icons getMetal() {
            Icons icons = new Icons();
            try {
                LookAndFeel save = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
                LookAndFeel laf = new MetalLookAndFeel();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
                icons.collapsed = (Icon) UIManager.get(COLLAPSED_ICON);
                icons.expanded = (Icon) UIManager.get(EXPANDED_ICON);
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(save);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            return icons;
        }
    }

    public JTreePanel(Icons pair) {
        UIManager.put("Tree.collapsedIcon", pair.collapsed);
        UIManager.put("Tree.expandedIcon", pair.expanded);
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        this.add(tree);
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTreePanel(Icons.getDefault()));
        frame.add(new JTreePanel(Icons.getMetal()));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you make the assumption that TreeUI that you are using is an `instance of` `BasicTreeUI`, you can do the following:

```
TreeUI tui = treeInstance.getUI();
if (tui instanceof BasicTreeUI) {
  ((BasicTreeUI)tui).setCollapsedIcon(myIcon);
}
```

Comment: +1 that's what SwingX' JXTree is doing as well :-) Just beware: it has to be update on toggling the LAF ... which JXTree forgets as well ... cough

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can see is to create your own version of JTree from the [Java source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JTree.java) that allows you to define the icons for each JTree.

I see that JTree gets the icons from [javax.accessibility.AccessibleContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext.java#AccessibleContext.getAccessibleIcon%28%29) and eventually some defined class of the `AccessibleIcon` interface.

Comment: hmm ... curious: where do you see a tree getting its collapsed/expanded icons from the accessibleContext? getIcon in super returns null and I can find no obvious override.