# How to change a JOptionPane Theme

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to make a simple JOptionPane but don't want the Java buttons/icon theme instead would like the windows button/icon. Now can I change it to the windows theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are created using the current LAF. No guarantee that it will work but you can do something like:

1. save current LAF
2. set LAF to Windows
3. display JOptionPane
4. restore LAF to saved LAF

See [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link, solved the problem.

What I did was add

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

Comment: +1 for leveraging the native L&F; a related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14262706/230513).